# Does deploy to Heroku interrupt current web processes?

Tags: heroku

When I deploy to heroku are web requests interrupted? If someone is uploading a file for example which takes 10 seconds or so (I know I should use a delayed job) and a deploy happens in the middle of this request, what happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the current requests (including that file upload) will continue to run, but all new requests will be delayed until the new version of the app has booted.

Comment: I belive that depends on the web server you are using. Are you sure they get delayed and not just refused?